# How to change the user password on all nodes of a (pbs) linux cluster

Tags: linux, cluster, passwd

There are a number of cluster commands that allow performing operations on all cluster nodes at once, e.g. `cexec`, as in `cexec mkdir /scratch/something`.

How can I change the password on all nodes at once for a user?

Comment: That's a good reason why admins use  LDAP or Kerberos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
for i in serverlist;do
   ssh $i "usermod --password $(echo my_new_password | openssl passwd -1 -stdin) USERNAME"
done
```

usermod doesn't prompt but the password needs to be encrypted first.

Comment: Seems to work as root. If I try it as regular user, I get in trouble with permissions.